# Can't add row to DataGridView with BindingList

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagridview, bindinglist

I'm writing C# WPF application. I'm new to it and tried to load a List to the DataGrid and failed. Then I added a WinForm to my WPF solution with DataGridView.
when I loaded the list to the DataGridView.DataSource I didn't had the '*' row to add new row even though the AllowUserToAddRows property is True, I converted the List to BindingList and still there's now new row. I've searched everywhere but everyone says that the BindingList solved them the problem. Is it because its a WinForm in WPF application?
How do i fix that?

Comment: have you checked the readonly property of the datagridview?

Comment: please show the relevant code

Comment: Forget winforms. Post the relevant code and XAML.

Comment: Yes Mohammad, the ReadOnly is false, I'll check OmegaMan answer and if it doesn't work i'll post the code. Thanks for now.

Answer (score 0):

Focus on using WPF, the winforms plugin works, but one finds due to the idiosyncrasis of the process it is truly not optimal.

---

Here is a basic example I have created which binds to a common list array. You can use an ObservableCollection or a simple generic list. In WPF one primarily defines the look/feel in xaml and then binds data to that. The `ItemsSource` is standard way of getting items into the datagrid to be shown.

```
Window.Resources>
    <model:People x:Key="People">
        <model:Person First="Joe"   Last="Smith"   Phone="303-555 5555" />
        <model:Person First="Mary"  Last="Johnson" Phone="720-555 5555" />
        <model:Person First="Frank" Last="Wright"  Phone="202-555 5555" />
    </model:People>
</Window.Resources>
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{StaticResource People}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First" Binding="{Binding First}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="The Name" Binding="{Binding Last}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Phone Number" Binding="{Binding Phone}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phone}" />
       </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

The result is the list with a rows template which opens upon click:

[image: WPF DataGrid]

Now most likely you will not use a Static Resource defined in Xaml to bind to just as I have shown, instead one places oa VM (ViewModel) class instance which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and creates a *People* property.

The VM can be accessed from the page's data context after it is most likely instantiated in code behind such as

```
public MyPage()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     DataContext = new MyPageViewModel(); // Contains logic for the 'People' Property of a list of people.

}
```

}

Then one changes the binding in my example above to bind to the page's datacontext *which is inheirted from the page because nothing was set* for the datagrid control.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
```

---

For a complete MVVM example see my blog [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it, the default constructor of the binding object was not public.
And on the way I got it to bind with the WPF DataGrid with ItemsSource (which is weird becaue when i tried it before i had the columns headers, and rows in the number of the items in the list, but no data in the rows.. but if it works dont touch it :) )
Thanks everyone.